# Get the key and value difference between to similar objects in PHP

Tags: php, object, comparison

I have two similar objects: 
Object old:

```
object(Party)#203 (16) {
  ["connection":protected]=>
  object(Connection)#202 (6) {
    ["token":"Connection":private]=>
    string(64) "xyzxxyzxyz"
    ["url":"Connection":private]=>
    string(33) "https://api.test.com"
    ["singularAction"]=>
    string(5) "party"
    ["pluralAction"]=>
    string(7) "parties"
    ["action"]=>
    string(5) "party"
  }
  ["emailAddresses"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(273530863)
      ["type"]=>
      NULL
      ["address"]=>
      string(19) "test@gmail.com"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(274183291)
      ["type"]=>
      NULL
      ["address"]=>
      string(18) "testMail1@test.com"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(278650133)
      ["type"]=>
      NULL
      ["address"]=>
      string(26) "emailUpdate@test.co.uk"
    }
  }
}
```

And object updated:

```
object(Party)#201 (16) {
  ["connection":protected]=>
  object(Connection)#202 (6) {
    ["token":"Connection":private]=>
    string(64) "xyzxxyzxyz"
    ["url":"Connection":private]=>
    string(33) "https://api.test.com"
    ["singularAction"]=>
    string(5) "party"
    ["pluralAction"]=>
    string(7) "parties"
    ["action"]=>
    string(5) "party"
  }
  ["emailAddresses"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(273530863)
      ["type"]=>
      NULL
      ["address"]=>
      string(19) "test@gmail.com"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(274183291)
      ["type"]=>
      NULL
      ["address"]=>
      string(18) "testMail1@test.com"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(278650133)
      ["type"]=>
      NULL
      ["address"]=>
      string(26) "emailUpdate@test.co.uk"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(1) {
      ["address"]=>
      string(27) "testMailtest12345@gmail.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Visually the difference is the last email address appearing as the last entry in the updated object. How can I highlight that difference in PHP and grab it?
I would like to check every entry of both objects, spot the differences in terms of key and value and do something with it.

What I've managed to write is this:

```
//Get the updated object....  
        $newObject = $this;
        //Now get the object before update was executed...
        $oldObj = $this->oldObject;

        //Remove object memebers from the new object for easy comparison with the old...
        unset($newObject->oldObject, $newObject->about, $newObject->createdAt, $newObject->updatedAt, $newObject->lastContactedAt, $newObject->pictureURL);
        //Remove object memebers from the old object....
        unset($oldObj->about, $oldObj->createdAt, $oldObj->updatedAt, $oldObj->lastContactedAt, $oldObj->pictureURL);

        $varsNewObj = get_object_vars($newObject);
        $varsOldObj = get_object_vars($oldObj);
        //Remove further unneeded memebers....
        unset($varsNewObj['connection']);
        unset($varsOldObj['connection']);

        $arrayData = [];

        foreach ($varsNewObj as $values) {
            if (is_string($values) && $values != null) {
                var_dump('New Values: ' . $values);
            }
            if (is_array($values)) {
                foreach ($values as $value) {
                    if (is_string($value) && $value != null) {
                        //var_dump($value);
                    }
                    if (is_array($value)) {
                        foreach ($value as $v) {
                            if ($v != null) {
                                //var_dump($v);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

What the code above does is to get every string that is needed for comparison from the new object. The same principle can be applied to the $oldObj, however I am puzzled on how to do the comparison later on as what I have in mind seem that doesn't work.

Comment: you can start maybe with `get_object_vars` ([manual link](http://php.net/manual/function.get-object-vars.php)) and compare them. Does it have to be recursive?

Comment: Unfortunately yes.

Comment: well i don't have time to write it for you (and not the site's purpose too), but i wrote similar recursive functions in javascript (actually to find a specific key in object structure) that can inspire you if you're interested

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: this is not really an answer, just a methodology to solve his problem, as I don't have time to fully explain but want to help still. You can vote if you like but there's no need, this answer could be deleted if question is updated with the asker's try.

So this is a basic example of how to do similar things recursively. I'm here directly returning the element found, where in your case you should maybe fill an array (or two if you want results for original and modified values to be separated). You also shouldn't break like i did, because i expect only one result while you are not.

the test `if('scope' in e_t){` is the recursive condition here, in your case, it will be a test on the type of the value to know if you want to go deeper (array, object?), you didn't precise what type of elements you want to search in for recursion, if all of them, you will maybe have to make cases on the type (not same way to iterate on properties). You didn't precise the output format too, so you'll have to do it.

The example:

```
            function _recursiveSearch(scope, objId, identifier){
                var scope_t = scope, e_t, k_t, r_t = false;
                for(k_t in scope_t){
                    if(scope_t.hasOwnProperty(k_t)){
                        e_t = scope_t[k_t];
                        if(identifier in e_t && e_t[identifier] === objId){
                            return e_t;
                        }
                        if('scope' in e_t){
                            r_t = _recursiveSearch(e_t.scope, objId, identifier);
                            if(r_t !== false){
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return r_t;
            }
```

EDIT FOR PHP: there are tricky parts i had forgotten to mention, be careful that `===` with objects in PHP will compare their reference. If you want to compare properties names and their values, use `==`. For the methodology, be sure not to record 2 properties as different just because they are not equal, because it can be one of their inner properties that differ if they are objects, well, not that simple, in fact!

Comment: Thanks for the info,  but still I cannot figured it out the correct methodology. For a reason or the other the comparison not always performs correctly.

Comment: @ao-pack i edited for your comment, at one point, you should also edit your question with the code you wrote, it will be easier for people to help

Comment: I've updated the question with some of my problems. If you could have a look and point me towards the right way that would be great. I know that probably there's something wrong but I cannot do any better for now as I don't have much experience.

Comment: won't be able to have a look before a couple of hours, it's the rush here :o

Comment: I'll keep trying and update the thread if I'll find something but i doubt it though.